How can I implement gzip or zip compression/decompression for data stored in DynamoDB using Spring Boot repositories?
I am working on a Spring Boot application that uses DynamoDB as the database. I would like to compress the data before writing it to DynamoDB (as it can pass the limit of 400Kb and not too much), and then decompress it after reading from DynamoDB.
Is there a doc or a way to configure this at the mapping level or repository? Any sample code or pointers on how to integrate this functionality would be greatly appreciated.

There is HTTP response compression functionality available in Spring Boot itself that support GZIP type compression/decompression.
I came across an article that might help with your specific requirements:
Spring Compression
